# Has anyone seen a huge painting of a warrior on a field in DAYZ?

Tags: dayz-standalone

On the map of DayZDB, I have heard there is a HUGE paiting on it (of a primitive warrior). Has anyone seen it in game or have a picture(s) of it?

Comment: This would appear to be an ingame replica of the [Cerne Abbas Giant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerne_Abbas_Giant) which is located in Dorset, England.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Number 4 in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1UrWdrkLh4&feature=youtu.be) looks like what you're talking about. A giant Native American Warrior made of dirt paths, only visible from above.

Here's the relevant screenshot from the video:

[image]

EDIT: A more cultured user than me pointed out that it's in fact a replication of the Cerne Abbas Giant in England, as seen below.

http://www.nationaltrust.org.uk/cs/Satellite?blobcol=urldata&blobheader=image%2Fjpeg&blobheadername1=Content-Disposition&blobheadername2=MDT-Type&blobheadername3=Content-Type&blobheadervalue1=inline%3B+filename%3D936%252F794%252Fntpl_2170_thumb_460x0.jpg&blobheadervalue2=abinary%3B+charset%3DUTF-8&blobheadervalue3=image%2Fjpeg&blobkey=id&blobtable=MungoBlobs&blobwhere=1349118642383&ssbinary=true

Comment: He's not American he's English. It's an in game replica of the Cerne Abbas Giant which is located in Dorset, England.

Comment: @DMK Just repeating what I found from my searches. Fixed.